# Highlight cells if column contains a given number X times

Tags: excel, worksheet-function, conditional-formatting

I have a large Excel spreadsheet with a column that has an identifying number.  Each unique number will occur at least 12 times.  I would like to highlight those numbers that appear more than 12 times.  Is there a way to do this non-programmatically?

Comment: I actually think @Remnant's version is better, you just need to select the whole sheet, then put it in and Excel will handle all of the relative referencing.  It can't be used in the cell proper, but for CF it works great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Conditional Formatting:

```
=COUNTIF(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(1,COLUMN())&":"&  
         ADDRESS(65536,COLUMN())),INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(), COLUMN())))>=12
```

Select the entire sheet, then choose Conditional Formatting.  Apply this formula, and pick the formatting you'd like.  It will work for any cell, in any column.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose in column A you have all your numbers. Then to highlight values that occur more than 12 times do as follows:

1. **Format > Conditional Formatting...**
2. In first dropdown select **Formula Is**
3. In the adjacent box type `=COUNTIF(A:A, A1) > 12`
4. Now select the desired color to highlight

Does this help?

Comment: i'm using Excel 2007 and under conditional formatting i don't see an option for 'formula is'.  something that i'm missing?

Comment: @dzilla, start with the 'New Rule' menu item.